# Consumir Webservice con asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Buenas Tardes quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy intentando consumir un servicio. por lo que me han dicho que consuma del servicio **DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest**  luego cuando consulta el resultado me votara otro servicio que se llama **DtoDividendo**  pero sale un error al consumir el servicio como Time Out

por la cual tiene estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi error me sale cuando intento ingresar  la propiedad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 protected void btnCalcular_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SvcCreditoExterno.SvcCreditoExternoClient sv = new SvcCreditoExterno.SvcCreditoExternoClient();

            SvcCreditoExterno.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest svs = new SvcCreditoExterno.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest();
            svs.AjustarTabla = txtAjustarTabla.Text;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SvcCreditoExterno.SvcCreditoExternoClient sv = new SvcCreditoExterno.SvcCreditoExternoClient();

SvcCreditoExterno.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest svs = new SvcCreditoExterno.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest();

svs.AjustarTabla = SvcCreditoExterno.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioMetodosAjusteTabla.AjustePrimeraCuota;

sv.ConsultarTablaAmortizacion(svs);
```